# Changing a calculated value in a label when a button is pressed in c#

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to programming; I know the basics of C and even less in C#.  I'm trying to write a program for my job that will allow the user to enter a value, this value will increase or decreased a contract amount.  I've looked everywhere and can't find the exact answer I need.  I tried a for loop until I read that a Windows Form is a loop.

The issue I'm having is every time a user enters a second value the program calculates the amount from the original contract value, it's not keeping the updated value after the calculation. If I was writing this as a console app I could figure out but I don't have a lot of experience with Forms.

here is my code for the Button_Click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const double CONTRACT_BALANCE = 229481.65;
        const double SUB_BALANCE = 196817.63;

        double subBal = SUB_BALANCE;
        double bal = CONTRACT_BALANCE;
        double enterPayment = 0;


        subBalLabel.Text = subBal.ToString("C");
        balanceLabel.Text = bal.ToString("C");


            //User Input Payment
            enterPayment = Double.Parse(payCOTextBox.Text);

            // balances
            subBal = subBal + enterPayment;
            bal = bal + enterPayment;


            // Text Labels

            subBalLabel.Text = subBal.ToString("C");
            balanceLabel.Text = bal.ToString("C");



            // Update Balance Label
            subBalLabel.Update();
            balanceLabel.Update();


             // Clear Text Box
            payCOTextBox.Clear();
```

Comment: Move the `const` variables outside of the button's click event. You're resetting the values every time the button is pressed.

Comment: @TestWell - How would that help?

Comment: You can not use hard coded values for the balances, these have to be stored in a file or someplace out of the program.

Comment: Constants don't change values. every time a user clicks a button and enters this method, the balance will be set to 229481.65 and the subbalance to 196817.63. The easiest way to keep track of the current values would be to get the balance from the balanceLabel.Text and the subBalance from the subBalLabel.Text instead of the constants

Comment: @Icemanind - Just like the answer says.

Comment: @TestWell - But the answer does more then just move the const variables outside the scope. Doing nothing to his original code except moving the const variables would have done nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `subbal` and `bal` variables are **local** to the method, which means they don't hold their values across calls.  Move them out to Class/Form level so they can be used over time:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    const double CONTRACT_BALANCE = 229481.65;
    const double SUB_BALANCE = 196817.63;

    double subBal = SUB_BALANCE;
    double bal = CONTRACT_BALANCE;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        subBalLabel.Text = subBal.ToString("C");
        balanceLabel.Text = bal.ToString("C");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        double enterPayment = 0;

        subBalLabel.Text = subBal.ToString("C");
        balanceLabel.Text = bal.ToString("C");

        //User Input Payment
        enterPayment = Double.Parse(payCOTextBox.Text);

        // balances
        subBal = subBal + enterPayment;
        bal = bal + enterPayment;

        // Text Labels
        subBalLabel.Text = subBal.ToString("C");
        balanceLabel.Text = bal.ToString("C");

         // Clear Text Box
        payCOTextBox.Clear();
    }

}
```